# Pasar lista de strings desde C++ a C#

Tags: c#, c++

Tengo una librería en C++ que se conecta con una cámara y quiero usarla en un programa C#, y como tengo bastante olvidado C++ necesitaba una ayudita.

La idea es obtener un listado de dispositivos conectados con la librería de C++ y pasarla a C#.

Mi programa en C++ es el siguiente:

```
int escribirArchivo(string *data, int num)
{
    int nError = siNoError;
    SI_64 nDeviceCount = 0;
    SI_WC szDeviceName[4096];
    int nIndex = -1;

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s = "";

    std::ofstream ofs("test.txt", std::ofstream::out);

    SI_CHK(SI_Load(LICENSE_PATH));

    SI_CHK(SI_GetInt(SI_SYSTEM, L"DeviceCount", &nDeviceCount));
    wprintf(L"Device count: %d\n", nDeviceCount);

    ofs << "Lista de Dispositivos: " << endl;

    // Iterate through each devices to print their name
    for (int n = 0; n < nDeviceCount; n++)
    {
        SI_CHK(SI_GetEnumStringByIndex(SI_SYSTEM, L"DeviceName", n, szDeviceName, 4096));
        //wprintf(L"\t%d: %s\n", n, szDeviceName);

        wstring ws(szDeviceName);
        // your new String
        string nombre_dispositivo(ws.begin(), ws.end());


        data[n] = nombre_dispositivo;
        // Show String
        ofs << "Dispositivo " << n << " " << nombre_dispositivo << endl;


    }

    ofs.close();


Error:
    if (SI_FAILED(nError))
    {
        char szInput[256] = "";
        wprintf(L"An error occurred: %s\n", SI_GetErrorString(nError));
        ss.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        char szInput[256] = "";
        wprintf(L"It all went well!\n");
    }

    // Cleanups the buffer, closes the camera and unloads SpecSensor
    SI_Close(g_hDevice);
    SI_Unload();

    return SI_FAILED(nError) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

La siguiente instrucción me devuelve un puntero wchart_t con el nombre de cada dispositivo.

```
SI_CHK(SI_GetEnumStringByIndex(SI_SYSTEM, L"DeviceName", n, szDeviceName, 4096));
```

Luego lo convierto a string y lo almaceno en un "string *data"

```
    wstring ws(szDeviceName);
    // your new String
    string nombre_dispositivo(ws.begin(), ws.end());


    data[n] = nombre_dispositivo;
```

En C# defino así la funcion:

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\Users\usuario\Dropbox\ANFACO\VISUAL_STUDIO\HIPERESPECTRAL\PRUEBA\Debug\Camara.dll",
        CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int escribirArchivo(string[] bytes, int size);
```

Y hago lo siguiente:

```
    private void seleccionDispositivos()
    {
        string[] data = new string[2];

        escribirArchivo(data, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
        }
    }
```

Lo que pasa es que obtengo el error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.AccessViolationException' en
>   Principal.exe
>
> Información adicional: Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria
>   protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.

Supongo que tendré que usar "`IntPtr`" en C# pero no sé muy bien como implementarlo.

Alguna ayuda? Gracias de antemano

---

Gracias por tu ayuda Trauma. El tipo de archivo `SI_WC szDeviceName[4096]` es un wchart_t no un chart.

Modifiqué el programa en C++ y me quedó así:

```
int escribirArchivo(wchar_t  *buff, int length)
{
    wchar_t *ptr = buff;
    int nError = siNoError;
    SI_64 nDeviceCount = 0;
    int nIndex = -1;
    SI_WC szDeviceName[4096];

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s = "";

    // RELLENAMOS EL BUFFER CON 0
    memset(buff, 0, length);

    std::ofstream ofs("test.txt", std::ofstream::out);

    SI_CHK(SI_Load(LICENSE_PATH));

    SI_CHK(SI_GetInt(SI_SYSTEM, L"DeviceCount", &nDeviceCount));
    wprintf(L"Device count: %d\n", nDeviceCount);

    ofs << "Lista de Dispositivos: " << endl;

    // Iterate through each devices to print their name
    for (int n = 0; n < nDeviceCount; n++)
    {
        SI_CHK(SI_GetEnumStringByIndex(SI_SYSTEM, L"DeviceName", n, szDeviceName, 4096));
        //wprintf(L"\t%d: %s\n", n, szDeviceName);

        wcscat(ptr, szDeviceName);
        ptr += wcslen(szDeviceName);

        wstring ws(szDeviceName);
        // your new String
        string nombre_dispositivo(ws.begin(), ws.end());
        // Show String
        ofs << "Dispositivo " << n << " " << nombre_dispositivo << endl;

    }

    ofs.close();


Error:
    if (SI_FAILED(nError))
    {
        char szInput[256] = "";
        wprintf(L"An error occurred: %s\n", SI_GetErrorString(nError));
        ss.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        char szInput[256] = "";
        wprintf(L"It all went well!\n");
    }

    // Cleanups the buffer, closes the camera and unloads SpecSensor
    SI_Close(g_hDevice);
    SI_Unload();

    return SI_FAILED(nError) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Si desde C# hago esto:

```
private void seleccionDispositivos()
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(20000); 

    escribirArchivo(sb, sb.Capacity);

    // Display the number of characters in the StringBuilder and its string.
    Console.WriteLine("{0} chars: {1}", sb.Length, sb.ToString());
}
```

Ya no me dá el error de System.AccessViolationException, pero no me acaba de funcionar, porque a la salida obtengo:

```
1 chars: F
```

Sin embargo en mi archivo test.txt obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Lista de Dispositivos: 
Dispositivo 0 FileReader
Dispositivo 1 FX10 with Dalsa
```

No podría recibir en C# un array de strings donde cada elemento del array fuera una cadena de texto con el nombre del dispositivo?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser un problema con el manejo de memoria entre los runtimes de C++ y C#, hay que seguir unos protocolos estrictos y cerrados para pasar memoria entre ambos runtimes; no puedo decirte nada más por el momento sin investigar un poco.

Comment: Editado ... creo que ahora si, que es la *refinitiva* :-)

Answer (score 11):

Antes de nada: **Ni idea de C#**, pero basándome en [esta respuesta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752001/8663418), vemos que tu problema está en que has utilizado una formación de `string` de C# ... que no tienen nada que ver ni con el típico `char *` ni con la clase `std::string` de C++.

Ese es el problema: Desde C++ estás interpretando los datos como algo que no son ... con el resultado que ya has comprobado: *comportamiento indeterminado*. Lo que viene a ser *que peta*, según la nomenclatura moderna :-)

## Edición final

Edición global, con todas las modificaciones aplicadas. La respuesta es grande ... y publicar todas las modificaciones, una a continuación de otra ... esto parecería un libro.

Muchisimas gracias al usuario [**@gbianchi**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi); sin su ayuda, esto no hubiera sido posible.

### Problemas

- Un `string` de C# **no** es compatible con C++. Y a la inversa.
- Se utilizan, en C++, cadenas `wchar_t`, que son **dependientes de la plataforma**; en Windows, se usa un tipo **de 16 bits** para ello.
- Se requiere enviar **mas de una cadena** entre ambos lenguajes. Desde C#, se entiende que después del `0` final de una cadena, **no hay nada mas**.

### Errores en el código de la pregunta

#### C++

```
int escribirArchivo( string *data, int num ) {
```

Ese es completamente erróneo. Un `string` de C# no tiene nada que ver con un `std::string` de C++ ... ni un `string[]` de C# se parece en nada a un `string *` de C++.

#### C#

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\usuario\Dropbox\ANFACO\VISUAL_STUDIO\HIPERESPECTRAL\PRUEBA\Debug\Camara.dll",
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

`CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` funcionaría ... si las cadenas en C++ usaran el tipo `char`. Pero **no** es así, son cadenas `wchar_t`.

```
string[] data = new string[2];
```

Ya hemos visto que `string[]` de C# **no** es compatible con `string *` de C++.

### Solución

#### C++

```
int escribirArchivo( wchar_t *buff ) {
  int nError = siNoError;
  SI_64 nDeviceCount = 0;

  std::ofstream ofs( "test.txt", std::ofstream::out );

  SI_CHK( SI_Load( LICENSE_PATH ) );

  SI_CHK( SI_GetInt( SI_SYSTEM, L"DeviceCount", &nDeviceCount ) );
  wprintf( L"Device count: %d\n", nDeviceCount );

  // SI NO HAY DISPOSITIVOS, SALIMOS.
  if( !nDeviceCount ) {
    ofs << "Sin dispositivos." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  *buff = 0;
  ofs << "Lista de Dispositivos: " << endl;

  for( int n = 0; n < nDeviceCount; ++n ) {
    if( n ) wcscat( buff, "&&" ); // SEPARADOR ENTRE NOMBRES -> &&

    wchar_t szDeviceName[4096];
    SI_CHK( SI_GetEnumStringByIndex( SI_SYSTEM, L"DeviceName", n, szDeviceName, 4096 ) );
    wcscat( buff, szDeviceName );

    ofs << "Dispositivo " << n << " " << szDeviceName << endl;
  }

  ofs.close( );

Error:
  if( SI_FAILED( nError ) ) {
    wprintf( L"An error occurred: %s\n", SI_GetErrorString( nError ) );
    // DEJAMOS EL ERROR EN EL BUFFER QUE RECIBIMOS COMO ARGUMENTO.
    wcscpy( buffer, SI_GetErrorString( nError ) );
  } else {
    wprintf(L"It all went well!\n");
  }

  SI_Close( g_hDevice );
  SI_Unload( );

  return SI_FAILED( nError ) ? -1 : reinterpret_cast< int >( nDeviceCount );
}
```

Nuestra función `escribirArchivo( )` devuelve:

- `== -1` -> Error. `sb` contiene el mensaje de error.
- `!= -1` -> Ok. Número de dispositivos detectados (pueden ser 0).

**¡ Cuidado !**. **No** comprobamos el tamaño del *bufer* que recibimos como argumento; hay que tener cuidado con el tamaño del mismo al generarlo desde C#, asegurándonos que es lo bastante grande.

Si la función devuelve `!= -1`, el *buffer* se rellena con los nombres de los dispositivos detectados, insertando `&&` para separar uno de otros.

#### C#

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\usuario\Dropbox\ANFACO\VISUAL_STUDIO\HIPERESPECTRAL\PRUEBA\Debug\Camara.dll",
            CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int escribirArchivo( StringBuilder buff );

private void seleccionDispositivos( ) {
  int result;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 20000 ); // 20000 caracteres.

  result = escribirArchivo( sb );

  if( result == -1 ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "Error: {0}", sb.ToString( ) );
  } else if( result == 0 ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "No se han detectado dispositivos" );
  } else {
    // OBTENEMOS LAS CADENAS; SE ENCUENTRAN SEPARADAS POR &&
    var lineas = sb.ToString( ).Split( new string[] { "&&" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

    Console.WriteLine( "Dispositivos detectados: {0}", result );

    foreach( string value in lineas) {
      Console.WriteLine( value );
    }
  }
}
```

Documentación adicional:

- [Default Marshaling for Strings (Microsoft)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#strings-used-in-platform-invoke)
- [CharSet Enum (Microsoft)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Me encantó tu respuesta :) pero tengo una pregunta, ¿por qué hay que generar el `StringBuilder` con tamaño de sobra? De acuerdo a la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.capacity?view=netframework-4.7.2) indica que la capacidad de alojamiento es dinámica, por default son 16 caracteres y si se llega a requerir un extra de capacidad, el IDE la va aumentando de acuerdo a la necesidad

Comment: Es dinámica ... desde C#, **no** desde C++. Este último no sabe nada del *runtime* de C#, ni puede acceder a el (bueno, igual si puede, pero no se como ... ) Estoy estudiando el tema, para solucionar lo indicado por el OP y dar una respuesta completa.

Comment: @Phi **Creo** (insisto, **creo**) que la interacción es correcta. Hay 2 problemas adicionales, que no vi en un principio: la función C++ trabaja con `wchar_t`, mientras que el `StringBuilder` espera `char` (hablando en C++). Y la función C++ rellena con varias secuencias de texto, separadas con `0`, y eso tampoco se como tratarlo desde C#.

Comment: @gbianchi Te remito a la pregunta en SO de donde saqué todo esto ... ya sabes que yo **ni idea** de C# :-D https://stackoverflow.com/q/20752001/8663418

Comment: Buenas, realicé los cambios como comentas en tu corrección y me devuelve esto por pantalla:

Dispositivos detectados:
F
F

Comment: ¡¡ Carajo !! Ya me está tocando las narices esto :-( Mirando ...

Comment: @Leo_Gz Tengo un error en `obtenerNombre( )` ... cambia `idx < current` por `current < idx`. No estoy seguro de que sea ese el problema, comenta por favor el resultado.

Comment: si corrijo eso, en la instrucción obtenerNombre(sb, devName, idx); me da System.AccessViolationException. No me imaginé que a priori una cosa tan básica como obtener dos strings fuese tan complicado... :(  

A lo mejor la solucción tendria que ser mediante un arreglo IntPtr, tendré que hacer un repaso a fondo de C++

Comment: Seria fácil si fuera 1. Tal vez se pueda transformar `sb` en un `Byte[]` y sacar las cadenas individuales así, ya que están separadas por un `0`. Pero ya te digo que de C#, ni idea :-(